# auto login in cloud using selenium [python]

Tags: python, selenium, autologin

I am trying to write a program that allows me to auto login on a cloud service. The fields corrensponding to the username and password in the HTML are:

```
<div class="formRow">
    <input type="text" name="emailOrUsername" ng-model="emailOrUsername" panono-text-box=
    "{ &quot;placeholder&quot;: &quot;states.account.logIn.emailOrUsername&quot;, &quot;required&quot;: true }
    " panono-focus="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid panonoTextBox ng-touched" placeholder=
    "Email or username *" spellcheck="false"> 
</div>

<div class="formRow">
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" panono-text-box=
    "{ &quot;placeholder&quot;: &quot;states.account.logIn.password&quot;, &quot;required&quot;: true }
    " class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid panonoTextBox" placeholder="Password *" spellcheck="false">
</div>
```

The code I have written is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

usernameStr = "my_username"
passwordStr = "my_password"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://mywebsite.com")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
if wait: 
    username = browser.find_element_by_name("emailOrUsername");
    password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")

    username.send_keys(usernameStr)
    username.send_keys(usernameStr)
```

I get this error message.

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"emailOrUsername"}

Comment: Have you tried with `xpath` method instead of `name` or `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to find those elements `by name` instead of `by id`

```
username = browser.find_element_by_name("emailOrUsername");
password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
```

Comment: Probably you need to put a wait for elements to be available

Comment: but you still using by id, there's no id the html. you should use `by name`

Comment: I have done it by name in my source code. I corrected the posted code

Comment: For testing you can increase the wait & try. But later you should use something like `wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Name, "emailOrUsername"))`
Read more on waits at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html